# why my navigation bar is good in chrome but wrapped in IE?

Tags: html, css

The website url is: `http://www.haorenao.cn`.
You can see the navigation bar with green works well in Chrome, but in IE it is wrapped by the browser.

Can anyone help me take a look? It really confuses me for a while, thanks.

Comment: Its working strange for me: in Chrome the nav bar links sit at the top of the image slider with the green bar above. In IE(9) it looks ok....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

apply `clear:both;` style for the navigation bar with green div as inline style. Otherwise make `overflow:hidden;` for the div `#topContentWrapper`